# Verify ethereum signed message using python

Tags: python

Is there any way to verify signed message using python?
Google  do not provide any useful info. I don't believe that there are no any lib which can do it. Any suggestions?

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Ethereum, using the elliptic curve *secp256k1* and using the hash algorithm *keccak256*, all the information required to verify a signature can be found in the [web3py documentation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#verify-a-message).